# Is there a way to introduce some basic type safety around IntPtrs returned from PInvoke'd methods?

Tags: interfaces, type-safety, interoperability

I have a C-Style API with methods that return pointers to native objects, e.g.

```
EXPORT hs::Pose3d* getJointEndPose(dh::Joint* joint);
```

And in C#,

```
[DllImport("Solver.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr getJointEndPose(IntPtr j);
```

To make the API a little nicer, I would like to distinguish between the types that the IntPtr's are pointing to. If the extern declarations can be made type-safe, that would be great, but even just more descriptive return types would be better than nothing.

Subclassing IntPtr is not possible because structs can't be inherited in C#. A using directive only applies to the file it's in.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 5):

My recommendation here is to keep the imported functions private inside some class, and use objects of that class to replace the `IntPtr`. For example, like this:

```
class Foo
{
    [DllImport("Solver.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetHandle();

    private IntPtr handle;

    public Foo()
    {
        handle = GetHandle();
    }
    
    // certain operations on handles
}
```

Now `Foo` becomes the typesafe replacement for the original `IntPtr`. In reality, `Foo` may encapsulate more than just one library call, and you may consider not to initialize `Handle` immediately in the constructor, but I guess you get the idea.

Of course, if you don't want to approach this "OO style", noone is hindering you to use a new struct with just one IntPtr attribute for each type of IntPtr, and introduce a mapping function for each imported function somewhere else, outside of those structs. Lets say we call the function `GetJointEndPose` to encapsulate `getJointEndPose`

```
struct Pose3D
{
    public readonly IntPtr IntPtr;
    public Pose3D(IntPtr x)
    {
        IntPtr = x;
    }
}
struct Joint
{
    public readonly IntPtr IntPtr;
    public Joint(IntPtr x)
    {
        IntPtr = x;
    }
}

 // ... somewhere else ...:
  public Pose3D GetJointEndPose(Joint joint)
  {
       return new Pose3D(getJointEndPose(joint.IntPtr));
  }
```

That gives you *more descriptive return types*, which can be used in a typesafe manner, but not much encapsulation, since it leaves access to the public `IntPtr` attribute open.